# Import tabular data while skipping field delimiters within text delimiters

Tags: import, data

I have data of the form:

```
X 1.213 'String Field With Lots of Spaces' 8.123
Y 2.43  'String Field With Lots of Spaces' 8.123
Z 4.83  'String Field With Lots of Spaces' 8.123
```

I'm trying to import it using the builtin `"Table"` format (or anything else that would work). Problem is, my field delimiter, a space, can occur within my text delimiters, as the above shows. Setting `"FieldDelimiters"->" "` and `"TextDelimiters"->"'"` does not do the trick. Is this possible or do I have to roll my own importer?

The data is a 2D array. The problem in reality is a little more complicated, in that I have two types of text delimiters, `'` and `"`, and one can contain the other. And so a string can be of the form `'String "With" Lots" of Quotes'` or `"String 'With' Lots' of Quotes"`. I don't *a priori* know the type of entries in a column, their ordering, or their widths. I.e. everything has to be inferred on the fly.

Note I am not asking for code to do this from scratch: I can do it myself. I'm just wondering if the builtin importers support this.

Comment: you should show a fully "complicated" example.  Do you know the structure? (symbol,number,string,number)

Comment: I updated it with some additional comments. I don't know the structure a priori. It has to be inferred, but the "Table" importer can usually do that.

Comment: `Import[file, "Table", "TextDelimiters" -> "'"]` works for the first example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) as [`"Text"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html). Then use [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html) and [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) to parse. Finally, [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to convert the numbers. It is bit of a run around. I guess this could be considered rolling your own importer.

With

```
str = "X 1.213 'String \"Field\" With \"Lots of\" Spaces' 8.123
  Y 2.43 \"String Field 'With' Lots 'of Spaces'\" 8.123
  Z 4.83 'String Field With Lots of Spaces' 8.123
  A 4.83 \"String Field With Lots of Spaces\" 8.123";
```

**Updated** for not knowing the types in each column.

```
StringCases[
  RegularExpression["((\"|')[^\\2]+?\\2)|([[:alpha:]])|(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"] :> 
   If["$4" != "", ToExpression@"$0", "$0"]]@StringSplit[str, "\n"]
```

> ```
> {{"X", 1.213, "'String \"Field\" With \"Lots of\" Spaces'", 8.123}, 
>  {"Y", 2.43, "\"String Field 'With' Lots 'of Spaces'\"", 8.123}, 
>  {"Z", 4.83, "'String Field With Lots of Spaces'", 8.123}, 
>  {"A", 4.83, "\"String Field With Lots of Spaces\"", 8.123}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This gets 2 out of three lines right:

```
ImportString[

"X 1.213 'String Field \"With\" Lots of Spaces' 8.123
Y 2.43  \"String Field 'With' Lots of Spaces\" 8.123
Y 2.43  \"string 1 ' \" 'string 2 \" '"

, "Table", "TextDelimiters" -> {"'", "\""}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

as you see if you are really general you end up with ambiguities. Most likely you need to import as "Lines" and work with string expressions.